# Print first 10 rows, followed by a string

Tags: sed, grep

I have a text file, and I want to extract the first 10 lines from it and then a specific string, then output this.

That is:

Input text file -> print first 10 lines -> print string starting with 'N' -> output to text file

Comment: Can you provide example input and output? I'm not certain I understand what you mean. Do you want to extract the first ten lines of a file and then echo a fixed string or extract the first ten lines of a file and all those afterwards that match a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'NR<11 && /^N/' infile > outfile
```

This will then from within the first `10` lines print only lines starting with  `N`.

Here is a `sed` version too:

```
sed -n '1,10{/^N/p}' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR<11{print;next} /^N/{print;exit}' file
```